# afxtempl.h Error 12 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have to migrate a C++ program written in 2002 into Visual Studio 2012. I get this error and I don't know why. I tried everything, but it doesn't work. The project is really big, but this .h file is included only in this cpp:

```
// ItemFromWorldSpan.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "booking.h"
#include "ItemFromWorldSpan.h"
#include "ItemFromWorldSpanPaxDlg.h"
#include "BookingDlg.h"
#include "BookingPax.h"
#include <MsXml2.h>
#include <afxtempl.h>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

#define TP_MSG_TYPE_PNRREQ (WM_USER + 1)
// ItemFromWorldSpan dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CItemFromWorldSpan, CTPDialog)
CItemFromWorldSpan::CItemFromWorldSpan(CTPBookingModule *pBookingModule,CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CTPDialog(CItemFromWorldSpan::IDD, pParent),m_pBookingModule(pBookingModule),m_pBokingDlg((CBookingDlg*)pParent)
{
    pPnrs = NULL;
}

CItemFromWorldSpan::~CItemFromWorldSpan()
{
    if (pPnrs)
        pPnrs = (delete pPnrs,NULL);
}

void CItemFromWorldSpan::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CTPDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX,IDC_LIST_PNR,cPnrList);
    DDX_Control(pDX,IDOK,butOk);
    DDX_Control(pDX,IDCANCEL,butCancel);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CItemFromWorldSpan, CTPDialog)
    ON_MESSAGE(TP_MSG_TYPE_PNRREQ, OnMessagePNRData)
    ON_NOTIFY(NM_DBLCLK,IDC_LIST_PNR,OnNMDblClickFlightList)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// ItemFromWorldSpan message handlers

BOOL CItemFromWorldSpan::OnInitDialog()
{
    CTPDialog::OnInitDialog();
    m_MsgList.SetContext((void*)this);
    SetHeaderSize(TP_DLG_HEADSIZE);
    SetFooterSize(TP_DLG_FOOTSIZE);
    SetWindowText("Collecting Data ...");
    cPnrList.SetExtendedStyle(cPnrList.GetExtendedStyle()|LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
    cPnrList.InsertColumn(0,"File Name",LVCFMT_LEFT, 100, 1);
    cPnrList.InsertColumn(1,"Lead Pax",LVCFMT_LEFT, 100, 2);
    cPnrList.InsertColumn(2,"Airline",LVCFMT_LEFT, 100, 3);
    CRect rcClient;
    cPnrList.GetClientRect(&rcClient);
    cPnrList.InsertColumn(3,"Route",LVCFMT_LEFT, rcClient.Width() - 301, 3);
    butOk.SetIconType(ICON_OK);
    butCancel.SetIconType(ICON_CANCEL);
    RequestPNRData();
    return TRUE;
}
void CItemFromWorldSpan::RequestPNRData()
{
    IXMLDOMDocument2 *pXmlDoc = NULL;
    HRESULT hr;
    CString str,str1,str2;
    try
    {
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DOMDocument, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
            IID_IXMLDOMDocument2, (void**)&pXmlDoc);

        if(FAILED(hr)||!pXmlDoc)
            throw 0;
        VARIANT_BOOL ok;
        str = "<operation type=\"request\" class=\"fetch\"><crs ident=\"wstair\"><pnrlist/></crs></operation>";
        hr = pXmlDoc->loadXML(_bstr_t(str),&ok);
        if(FAILED(hr) || (!ok))
            throw 0;
        SaveXML2file(pXmlDoc,"XML\\WSPNRSRequest.xml");
        if (m_MsgList.tp_send_xml(pXmlDoc,TP_MSG_TYPE_PNRREQ)<=0)
        {
            OutputDebugString("ItemFromWorldSpan: RequestPNRData: Cannot send request to server\n");
            throw 0;
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {

    }
    if(pXmlDoc)
        pXmlDoc->Release();
    return;
}
LRESULT CItemFromWorldSpan::OnMessagePNRData(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument2> pXmlDoc;
    pXmlDoc.Attach((IXMLDOMDocument2*)wParam);
    CComPtr<IXMLDOMNode> pChildNode;
    CString str;
    HRESULT hr;

    try
    {
        SaveXML2file(pXmlDoc,"XML\\WSPNRSReply.xml");
        if (CheckXMLStatus(pXmlDoc,&str)<=0)
        {
            str = "There was an error:\n" + str;
            MessageBox(str);
            throw 1;
        }
        hr = pXmlDoc->selectSingleNode(CComBSTR(_T("/operation/crs/pnrlist")),&pChildNode);
        if (FAILED(hr) || (pChildNode == NULL))
            throw 0;
        if (pPnrs)
            pPnrs = (delete pPnrs,NULL);
        pPnrs = new CWsPnrList;
        if (pPnrs == NULL)
            throw 0;
        if (!pPnrs->LoadData(pChildNode))
            throw 0;
        if (!pPnrs->GetDisplayData(ListDisplayData))
            throw 0;
        POSITION pos = ListDisplayData.GetHeadPosition();
        int i = 0;
        while (pos)
        {
            cPnrList.InsertItem(i,_T(""));
            cPnrList.SetItemData(i,reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(pos));
            CPnrDisplayData *pData = ListDisplayData.GetNext(pos);
            cPnrList.SetItemText(i,0,pData->FileName);
            cPnrList.SetItemText(i,1,pData->LeadPax);
            cPnrList.SetItemText(i,2,pData->AirLine);
            cPnrList.SetItemText(i,3,pData->Route);
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (...) 
    {
        pXmlDoc.Release();
    }
    return 0;
}

void CItemFromWorldSpan::OnNMDblClickFlightList(NMHDR *pNotifyStruct, LRESULT *result)
{
    POSITION pos = reinterpret_cast<POSITION>(cPnrList.GetItemData(reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNotifyStruct)->iItem));
    CPnrDisplayData *pData = (pData = NULL,ListDisplayData.GetAt(pos));
    if ((pData != NULL) && (pPnrs != NULL))
    {
        CWsPnr *pPnr =  (pPnr = NULL,pPnrs->GetPNR(pData->pnr_pos));
        if (pPnr != NULL)
        {
            CItemFromWorldSpanPaxDlg dlg(pPnr,m_pBokingDlg,this);
            dlg.DoModal();
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Can someone please help me? I am stuck!

Comment: The problem is almost certainly located in one of your own include files. Is that the *first* error or are there other ones?

Comment: @AndreiDobrin In your "Output" window you can switch the "Show output from" drop down to "Build Order" and then search for the first error, as suggested by [molbdnilo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo)

Comment: It is the only one. In this project this is the only file that includes "afxtempl.h", but this file is not made by the guys who wrote this program, it is a Visual Studio .h file so I say it is not from it. I read on some forums(I am trying for a time now to solve this error) that if you don't use the templates(from "afxtempl.h") correctly you can get these errors.

Answer (score 0):

The file that you pasted has this comment ate the top: `// ItemFromWorldSpan.cpp : implementation file`

Which I expect means that it is in fact ItemFromWorldSpan.cpp.

Your error however is from the file: afxtempl.h

afxtempl.h is not directly included, so you'll need to find that header and see if you can identify the error.

I notice that you have stdafx.h included at the top, which means that you're using precompiled headers. It's possible that afxtempl.h is included from there?